# Get all iframes in parent window having same origin from an iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, browser, cross-origin-resource-policy

I have a page in which I'm including iframes from two different domains i.e. like below

```
<!-- domain 1 frames -->
<iframe src="domain1/page1.html">
<iframe src="domain1/page2.html">

<!-- domain 2 frames -->
<iframe src="domain2/page1.html">
```

Now let's say I have the below javascript code in domain1/page1.html

```
var frames = window.parent.frames;
```

This will give me all iframes (iframe from domain 1 & domain 2) from parent windows. However, I want to get only iframes from domain 1. When I try to filter iframes from only domain 1 using the below code

```
var isSameOrigingIframe = window.location.host == window.parent.frames[i].location.host;
```

I receive a security exception (Cross-origin policy violation) as an iframe from domain 1 tries to access iframe domain 2.

My current solution relies on try-catch block as below

```
var isSameOrigingIframe = false;
try{
   isSameOrigingIframe = window.location.host == window.parent.frames[i].location.host;
}catch(e){
   isSameOrigingIframe = false;
}
```

The above solution works but is there is any safe way to get iframes only from the same domain? Or there is a better way to filter out iframes from the same domain.